# How to check if there is enough free space inside directory on Linux

Tags: sh, stat, du

I want to check all availalble space in directory A using 'stat'. Then I want to check the size of directory B using 'du' and if directory A has enough free space, then i want to copy B into A.

The question is what arguments I need to pass to the 'stat' and 'du' commands so that they will return their output in the same format (nodes, bytes, etc...)

Comment: "Available space in a directory" doesn't make much sense (with the caveat of quotas). What you want is the available space in the volume that contains the directory, yes?

Comment: you know about the `df -k .` command AND that a directory is usually sharing space with other directories under its mount point? Note that the last item in the output from above is labeled (something like) "Mounted on". Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

On Linux there is no limit to the files contained in a directory, there isn't even a limit on how many files can be placed in a directory.  This can all be found in the linux manpages.

Iff the *device* that A is on is different from the one B is on, you may be curious about how much available space there is left on A's *device*.  For that you use:

```
stat --file-system A B
```

Comment: Actually, there are limits to the number of files that can be in a directory, but that limit is typically so high as to be unimportant (in the billions).